# Single Line If Condition Not Evaluating Correctly

Tags: vb.net

I developed the following IEnumerable(of T) extension method to perform weighted average calculations.

For some reason, the code written below works correctly, but if I uncomment the line that says `'Return If(isNull OrElse den = 0, Nothing, num / den)` it returns a value of 0 when it should return nothing. This can be confirmed by calling the function on a list with no items. The correct way to call the function is:
`list.WeightedAverage(Function(x) x.ValueProperty, Function(x) x.WeightProperty)`. Because it is an extension method it needs to be put into a module.

```
<Extension>
Public Function WeightedAverage(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), valueSelector As Func(Of T, Decimal?), weightSelector As Func(Of T, Decimal?)) As Decimal?
    Dim num, den, tempDen As Decimal
    Dim tempNum As Decimal? = Nothing
    Dim isNull As Boolean = True
    For Each record In source
        tempNum = valueSelector.Invoke(record)
        tempDen = weightSelector.Invoke(record).GetValueOrDefault
        If tempNum.HasValue Then
            isNull = False
            num += tempNum * tempDen
        End If
        den += tempDen
    Next
    'Return If(isNull OrElse den = 0, Nothing, num / den)
    If isNull OrElse den = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return num / den
    End If
End Function
```

My question is why using the `If` statement on a single line does not work?

Comment: `Return If(isNull OrElse den = 0, New Decimal?, num / den)`

Comment: Return If(isNull OrElse den = 0, Nothing, num / den)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Plutonix. That works well. I find the nuances of working with nullables a bit frustrating at times.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Nothing` is not the same thing as `null` in C#.  It's closer to `default(T)`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I know it has been along time since this post, but I still don't understand this issue, and why single line "Return If(..." statement does not perform exactly like the multiple line If Else statement.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway In both cases, my code returns a value of Nothing, which I am expecting the CLR to coerce into a Nullable. I would be very happy if both ways resulted in a Decimal? where .HasValue = False, I would be unhappy, but understand if both ways return Decimal? where .Value = 0 (ie. a Nullable with the default value of the underlying type), but I am very confused why the two methods behave differently (one way returns a Nullable where .Value = 0 and the other return a Nullable where .HasValue = False). Can you further explain how your comment about Nothing and null relates to this issue?

Comment: I believe it's because in the single line `If`, the compiler must infer the type based on the true and false arguments.  The `If` operator requires that both arguments be the same type.  The compiler cannot infer a type from `Nothing` so it uses uses the expression `num/den` which is type `Decimal`.  If the opening condition of the `If` operator is false, it coerces `Nothing` to a `Decimal` (not Decimal?) which results in 0.  For the standard `Return`, it uses the return type of the method as the type which is `Decimal?` and therefore `Nothing` is coerced to that type.  I hope this makes sense

Comment: If you had defined `num` and `den` as `Decimal?` rather than just `Decimal` it would have produced the same result in either case because the `If` operator would then have coerced its result to `Decimal?`.

Comment: @chrisdunaway Awesome, your answer is very clear and makes good sense. I have been concerned to use the single line form of "if" because I did not understand this issue. With your advice, I can understand when it is and is not appropriate.